# Android how to Add double values to AndroidPlot library?

Tags: android, for-loop, double, androidplot

Hi all am creating one activity to Android plot library, In this am adding simple string values using this loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++, scale *= 5) {
         series[i] = new SimpleXYSeries("S");
         populateSeries(series[i], scale);
    }
```

in this series values add to Androidplot lib, it is working good useing this

```
   mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series[1],
            new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 50, 0), null,  null, null));
```

But i want to add double values in place of that series values

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / freqOfTone));  
        Toast.makeText(TouchZoomExampleActivity.this, " = = > " +sample[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    //  Log.i(" Touch zoom ===> ", "" + i + "== > "+ sample[i] );
    }
```

But this bouble valus not possible add my plot lib any one have idea help this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of series

```
XYSeries series = (XYSeries) new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(new Number[] { 1, 2, 3 }),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "title");
```